# anti image hotlinking (custom regex)

Tags: regex, .htaccess, hotlinking

I'd like to set up a regular expression that would disallow hotlinking of images that DO NOT end with the following pattern: -200.jpg

The "200" can actually be "150" or "250" or any number between 100-999 (that is to say 3 chars). The .jpg can be .jpeg or .png, Hotlinking of .gif is allowed.

I started with something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(.+\.)?mywebsite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule [^0-9]{3}\.(jpe?g|png)$ /img/hotlink.gif [NC,R,L]
```

For example: This should be allowed:
`h*ttp://mywebsite.tld/dir/dir/hello_sdfk456er_142.jpg-200.jpg` whereas this should be denied: `h*ttp://mywebsite.tld/dir/dir/hello_sdfk456er_142.jpg`

But this is not working.

Also, please consider the following:

I am using url_rewriting so that the html page that displays the image is like `h*ttp://mywebsite.tld/username/1337.jpg`

where 1337 stands for the id of the image in the database. The reason why I'm highlighting this subtility is because a rule like:

```
RewriteRule ![0-9]{3}\.(jpe?g|png)$ /img/hotlink.gif [NC,R,L]
```

would not work.

EDIT:

I just solved it adding some exceptions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(.+\.)?mywebsite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !-[0-9]{3}\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/[0-9]+\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|png)$  /img/hotlink.gif [NC,R,L]
```

If you know a "sexier" way please let me know.
Thanks anyway to the guy who gave it a try (deleted his messages?)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution has two flaws:

1. The 4th line with `/[0-9]+` will also allow hotlinking images that are named as just `200.jpg` (no hyphen).
2. The RewriteRule condition is missing, and thus will not allow hotlinking `.gif` images.

Here's an updated version:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(.+\.)?mywebsite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !-[0-9]{3}\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://mywebsite.com/img/hotlink.gif [NC,R,L]
```

You can read it as follows:

1. If referrer is not empty
2. And referrer is not my site
3. And an image is requested that doesn't end with allowed pattern (e.g. -123.gif)
4. Then show a hotlink.gif

Comment: The 4th line is just an escape for my url_rewriting, as I have some HTML pages called like h*ttp://mywebsite.tld/dir/dir/5465.jpg , which are not images actually but HTML pages. I don't host any image like "{NUMBER}.jpg", I rename all uploaded images so the anti-hotlink cannot be bypassed with that trick. My solution is actually working good enough, the only problem I have now is: if I add the .gif images to the anti-hotlink rule, the hotlink.gif image does not show up (kind of an endless loop?). Thank you.

Comment: What if instead of adding `.gif` you put `.*` as I suggested? Still endless?

Comment: Still fails that way. I added an exception to avoid the endless redirection loop, like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !/img/hotlink.gif$ [NC]` Also I feel like I am not getting same behaviour considering the browser... (Works fine with IE and Chrome, but FF sometimes triggers the anti-hotlink inexplicably. I don't get it... Maybe a cache problem.)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(.+\.)?mywebsite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !-[0-9]{3}\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/[0-9]+\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|png)$  /img/hotlink.gif [NC,R,L]
```